# Apache does not start

Tags: apache

I tried to start Apache from XAMPP control panel but it would not start. I had it running before. The following is the log

```
8:44:56 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
8:44:56 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
8:44:57 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
8:44:57 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
8:44:57 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:44:57 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:44:57 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:44:57 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:44:57 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
8:44:57 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

I tried to run Apache_start.bat and got the following error

```
Apache 2 is starting...
http.exe: System error on line 560 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file C:/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I saw other posts for unable to start Apache, but my error seems to be different.

Can someone help?

Comment: So – does the file mentioned in the error message exist …?

Comment: I cannot find the file in C:/phpMyAdmin/, but I had Apache running yesterday.

Comment: I also tried to change the port as suggested in another post: Listen: 80 to Listen: 81 and ServerName localhost 80 to ServerName localhost 81, it didn't work. So I guess my problem is not a blocked port.

Comment: Well if the file doesn’t exist, then it should not be included in the `httpd.conf` on the mentioned line.

Comment: Have you started skype? if yes close it then try again?

Comment: I tend to think it is not really a missing file problem because Apache was running fine before I restart my computer and I did not change the httpd.conf file or remove any file. I do not have skype running.

Comment: `C:/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` is this file there? that is a different file and is what it is complaining about the path looks wrong as well. That file should have been in side `C:/xampp/apache/` somewhere and not at `c:/etc`. Try commenting the line 560 of your `C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf` and see what happens

Comment: As suggested by CBroe, I removed the line 560 of httpd.conf: include C:/etc/phpmyadmin/appache.conf and Apache started. Thanks CBroe!!!